# Convert to timeseries hourly data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame with dates going from `2012-04-18 00:00:00` to `2012-04-30 23:00:00`.

I want to convert it to a time series using the `ts` function but I can't manage to configure it.

I have tried:

```
newdata <- ts(data[-1], start = as.Date("2012-04-18"), freq = 312)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: *"but it doesn't seem to work"* How?

Comment: when i autoplot the ts the time axis isn't correct

Comment: Include that in your question! :)

Comment: And also explain how that time axis "isn't correct". What do you see? What do you *want* to see?

Comment: Just a guess (not knowing r), is that "freq" parameter the number of ticks you want on the timescale, or should it be the time interval between ticks (1 (hour), 60 (minutes) or such)?

Comment: normally ts is not used with daily data.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax for the `ts` function is a little different.
As it is written on the help page of `ts`:

> **start**: the time of the first observation. Either a single number or a
>   vector of two integers, which specify a natural time unit and a
>   (1-based) number of samples into the time unit. See the examples for
>   the use of the second form.

Try this:

```
newdata <- ts(data[-1], start = c(2012, 4.5), freq = 312).
```

However when working with intraday data I would rather recommend the `xts` package and work with `xts` objects instead on `ts` objects.

Comment: Thnx a lot for your fast reply ! Unfortunately the time axe still isn't correct (it goes until 2013 when I would like from 2012-04-18 00:00:00 to 2012-04-30 23:00:00)

Comment: firstHour <- 24*(as.Date("2012-04-30 23:00:00")-as.Date("2012-04-18 00:00:00"))
newdata <- ts(data[-1],start=c(2012,firstHour),frequency=24*365)